# How to wait for api call to complete when called in ngOnDestroy function?

Tags: javascript, angular, lifecycle

I have a scenario where i have to send data to api (database) before specific component is destroyed. As its described in angular2 life cycle, one method is executed before component is destroyed and its called `ngOnDestroy`. But as specified in documentation, that is an void function so it does not wait for some results to return.

My quesiton is how can i perform my call to api in ngOnDestroy function and wait while it completes?

If i just call update function it works, but when i route from one component to another, the data from first component are not yet updated while next component loads old data (if i hit refresh then i get new data). So problem is that i cannot wait for update function to execute fully and then allow component destruction and routing to next component which will load correct, updated data:

```
updateData(data: any, callback?: Function) {
    this.apiService.update(data).then(response => {
        callback(response);
    }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.updateData(this.data);
}

// Maybe i could somehow use callback functionality to postpone execution of ngOnDestroy function
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.updateData(this.data, response => {

    });
}
```

Or is there any other way to solve this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing something like this try this approach much cleaner and better i guess.

Make use of a Shared service, pass on the r values to the shared service on `Destroy` and then when navigating to the second component. have a Router resolve that will make sure data is populated and kept at your disposal when the component is loaded.

For shared services check this [**LINK**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)- question 2 and for Router resolve [**LINK**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/guard).

You may also reach out for redux or ngrx areif you want better readability [**LINK**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx)

Comment: So i should make a service where i change the state that some process is working in background and in callback i change the state in the service (from working=true to working=false and emit the finished event). And then in new route i check if working value is true and then subscribe to an event to notify me when its done. And then i can make new request to API which will contain new data. Because i can get from component A to component B inside application which should save data to database before routing, because i can also access component B directly.