# How is component garbage collected if an async function is called from within ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook?

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await

I have an angular component and inside ngOnDestroy hook I want to add asynchronous function that makes http call to delete something for example. I wonder how is memory managed and what is the scope of the callback function ? If garbage collector decides to release memory by reference does it mean that the component will stay in memory until the delete callback is complete ? Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svs26m) and examples of what I'm testing.

First:

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
    this.http.delete(...)
  }
```

Since I didnt provide .then(...) callback does it mean component can be completely unloaded from memory ?

Second:

```
 async ngOnDestroy() {
    await this.http.delete(...)
  }
```

Why does component get destroyed and doesn't await for the delete() to complete ?

Third:

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
    this.http.delete(...).then(console.log);
  }
```

Since I provided callback function does it mean component will stay in memory until the callback func completes ?

How can I see what's happening in memory allocation ? Is there a way to see what garbage collector does or maybe specify a callback function when certain object is released from memory ? Thanks

EDIT

Based on this [Memory Management MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) it appears that since 2012 Reference-counting algorithm has been replaced by Mark-and-sweep and I could expose garbage collector if I run my ng serve node process with --expose-gc flag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular4 - how to ensure ngOnDestroy finishes before navigating away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011471/angular4-how-to-ensure-ngondestroy-finishes-before-navigating-away) , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55001261/angular-5-asynchronous-service-calls-in-two-different-components-first-method, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196445/how-to-wait-for-api-call-to-complete-when-called-in-ngondestroy-function

Comment: None of these answer my questions about memory allocation and garbage collection. Pls take time to read and understand my question before marking it as duplicate